# php echo the link, but replace some url string , how?

Tags: php

I have this link : 
 `<a href="<?php echo Mage::getURL() ?>brands/<?php echo $_brand['label'] ?>">`
This will give me a result of 
`brands/Example%20Of%20My%20Brand` in the url and is not good,because it is 404.
The actual name of the brand is "Example Of My Brand" and the URL to reach this page "example-of-my-brand" so this is what i need to get
What I need to do is trim/replace? the %20 so it will be "-" and also if it is possible to make all the link lowercase?
Thank you very much, I hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$part1=Mage::getURL();
$part2=str_replace(" ", "-", urldecode($_brand['label']));
$newurl=strtolower($part1."brands/".$part2);
?>

<a href="<?php echo $newurl ?>">
```

Something like this should work.

If $part1 has any url-encoded character just use `urldecode` on it as well.

Comment: Hi thanks so much for your fast comment, it should be $_brand and i fixed. The lowercase now works great, how about replace the %20 with - ?

Comment: I fixed it. The %20 is a URL encoded character, the `urldecode` function should replace it with it's corresponding non-encoded value

Comment: Ah sorry, %20 equals a blank space, not a '-'. Editing my answer.

Comment: the part2 will give error in magento and page not load. Maybe some other way to str_replace or some typo error? thank you

Comment: there was a typo on that line, a `)` was missing at the end.

Comment: thanks so much, now perfect. Thanks everybody. How can i vote up? (requires 15 reputation)

Answer (score 1):

Actually %20 is space you try this

```
 <a href="<?php echo Mage::getURL() ?>brands/<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',$_brand['label']) ?>">
```

Check this for lower case

```
<?php 
  $link=Mage::getURL().'brands/'.str_replace(' ','-',$_brand['label']);
  $link=strtolower($link); 
?>

<a href="<?php echo $link;?>">
```

Comment: this good solution for space thank you, how can i also add the strlto ower on this? <a href="<?php echo strtolower Mage::getURL() ?>brands/<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',$_brand['label']) ?>">

Comment: if you want to change to hole url mean I have given you example check this

Answer (score 0):

first of all concat all this variable and string and then add this in href like this

```
 <?php    $abc = Mage::getURL();
$final =$abc.'brands'.$brand['label'];?>
 <a href="<?php echo $final?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace()`.

```
<a href="<php echo strtolower(str_replace('%20', '-', Mage::getURL().'brands/'.$_brand['label'])); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [getUrl documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters), I think you should be using:

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('', array('_use_rewrite' => true));
```

> _use_rewrite => Looks up the module/controller/action/parameters in the database for a search engine friendly equivalent.